# query a view with a list of data

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq

How can I query a view with data in a list?

For eg: Below, I have variable "data" where I store all the id's from a view to a list. I want to query a second view "vwStatus" such that it returns all the rows which has status displayed in the list(data)

Something like:

```
public ActionResult Index(string id)
{
    var data = (from p in db.vwdb.Where(p => p.ID == id)
                 group p by p.status into g select g.Key).ToList();

    ViewData.Model = db.vwStatus.Where(p => p.Status == data);           

    return View();
}
```

Hope I made it clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this:

```
var data = (from p in db.vwdb.Where(p => p.ID == id)
                 group p by p.status into g select g.Key).ToList();

//Here you'll get the data you want from the database:
ViewData.Model = db.vwStatus.Where(vw => data.Contains(vw.Id));

return View();
```

This shall work fine.

Regards.

Comment: I just realized you wanna fetch it by status. But if you don't store the status as well, there are no way you could retrieve it. My sugestion is to get by the Id, instead of the Status.